# $d(f(z)dz)=0$ iff $f$ satisfies Cauchy Riemann equations

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-forms

Define
$$d(\omega+i\nu)=d\omega + id\nu $$
$$(\omega+i\nu)\land(\theta+i\lambda)=\omega \land\theta-\nu\land\lambda+i(\nu\land\theta +\omega\land\lambda) $$
$$dz=dx+idy$$
Proof $d(f(z)dz)=0$ iff $f$ satisfies the Cauchy Riemann  equations
Idk where can i find information, please some help for bibliography or related questions

Comment: Have you learned about $\partial f = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}\,dz$ and $\bar\partial f = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}\,d\bar z$?

Comment: You might be interested in Chapter 5 of Donaldson's book _Riemann Surfaces_. The book has great exposition, but you should be careful of a few major typos scattered throughout it. I'm not sure if there are any in chapter 5, but if you know there are some typos they're pretty easy to spot.

Comment: Yeah, then just write it out in terms of real and imaginary parts and calculate. No big deal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

Say $f = u + iv$. Then

$$f \ dz = (u + iv)\ (dx + i \ dy) = (u \ dx - v \ dy) + i (v \ dx + u \ dy)$$

Now we can compute $d(f\ dz)$ using the usual computation rules for (real) differential forms. What do we get? What happens when we set the real and imaginary parts to be $0$ (since we're assuming $d(f \ dz) = 0$)?

---

I hope this helps ^_^